# Как собрать целые из бинарной строки без циклов?

Tags: алгоритм, php

Есть строка, в которой записаны 4 целых числа. Каждое может занимать разное число байт: 1, 2, 3 или 4. Эти длины известны.

Напр., дана строка `0x01AA02BBBB03CCDD` и длины содержащихся в ней целых: 2, 3, 2 и 1 байт ( 01AA - двухбайтовое первое число, и т.д.).

**Как красиво получить эти целые, не прибегая к циклам?**

Некрасивое решение: `unpack('C*', $string)` и по байту в цикле смещаю на нужно число бит и добавляю в нужную ячейку массива четырех результатов. Кажется, это неэффективно..

Comment: > Кажется, это неэффективно..

Если работает, то это эффективно.

Альтернативно приходит на ум только вырезать четыре строки, используя данные о смещении, и применять `hexdec()`, тут не сказать что что-то сильно отличается.

Еслисомневаетесь за скорострельность реализации, то можете взять конкурирующие алгоритмы и прогнать их через [athletic](https://github.com/polyfractal/athletic).

Comment: Ещё можно собрать pattern и разбить с помощью preg_match_all() по нему... На счёт эффективности вопрос спорный, но циклы будут не нужны
0x((?:.{2}){len1})((?:.{2}){len2})((?:.{2}){len3})((?:.{2}){len4}). Т.е. для примера 2,3,2,1 получим:

    $s='0x01AA02BBBB03CCDD';
    preg_match_all("/0x((?:.{2}){2})((?:.{2}){3})((?:.{2}){2})((?:.{2}){1})/", $s, $matches);
    print_r($matches);